# gitlab code quality: Changing configuration parameters for GitLab's CodeQuality?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ce

I have a local (community) GitLab server and I've recently enabled [Code Quality](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/testing/code_quality.html).

One of the tests is line length. A minor error is noted for lines longer than 100 characters.
I would like to change that to 120 characters instead (which is our standard) but I couldn't find a way to adjust/configure Code Quality itself.

Where can I adjust configuration for GitLabs' Code Quality feature? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple. GitLab uses `gitlab-pylint` which relies heavily on `pylint`. It's easy to configure gitlab's pylinter using the same configuration options available to pylint.

I coudln't find any documentation explicitly stating this but it was quite easy to figure out for myself.